# Incorrectly sum in a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

```
$dt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `member_territory` mt LEFT JOIN `drug_territory` dt ON mt.mt_ter = dt.t_id");

 while($t = mysql_fetch_array($dt)) {

     $total +=($t['t_reward']* $t['mt_lev'])*150;

     mysql_query("UPDATE `members` SET 
                 `drug_income` = '".$total."',
                 `drug_incometotal` = `drug_incometotal` + '".$total."', 
                 `wallet` = `wallet` + '".$total."' 
                 WHERE `playerid` = '".$t['mt_playerid']."'");

  }
```

So here is my code rather self explainingtary $total when inserted into `drug_income` that is correct but when ever it is inserted into `drug_incometotal` or `wallet` its incorrect.

im not sure why and i have tried everything to my knowledge to pull my head around it!!.

Any ideas why i am getting this incorrect result ( as i say `drug_income` is correct) only when i try to '+' it to something in the data base it returns an incorrect result.

Comment: Sounds like a nice, friendly game

Comment: What part of the code is incorrect.. :) seems fine as part of it inserts correctly but the rest doesnt.

Comment: Seems to me like the code works fine, but your algorithm is wrong. Are you sure you want to be incrementing `drug_incometotal` by the incrementing `$total` variable every time, or did you mean to only increase it once after the loop?

Comment: i dont want to increment just once after the loop...

Comment: You're safe from SQL Injection in this case, but you should still be using [parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/812837) anyways.  You also appear to be adding `total` as a string, which might be having an effect.  You should be able to do this as a single statement - ie `UPDATE members FROM member_territory` (or whatever), which should _also_ be faster than pulling the data into php for the calculation.  `drug_incometotal` appears to be a derived value, which generally shouldn't be stored - can you just query for this when necessary (or use a view)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i dont want to increment just once after the loop... –  user3740302 1 min ago

Okay then. So you should probably move your `UPDATE` query outside of the loop, right?

Comment: If i remove it out of the while loop it doesnt update at all :/

Comment: That would be because you're using `$t['mt_playerid']`. Is there anywhere else you can get the player ID from?

Comment: make a new query i guess... let me look thanks for your help..?

Comment: *hand over face* ..... thanks its has been fixed ;) fetched the previous query again outside of the while loop :)

Comment: ...Except the query is looping to update _multiple rows_, so it might be better to say he needs a _second_ `UPDATE` outside the loop... or a slightly different db design.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this modified update query

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `members` SET drug_income = ".$total.", drug_incometotal = drug_incometotal + ".$total.", wallet = wallet + ".$total." WHERE `playerid` = '".$t['mt_playerid']."'");
```

It may resolve your problem..

Comment: I'm having trouble spotting the difference. What have you changed, and why?

Comment: because in your update query you are using $total as a string type value that will be concatenated in your current value

Comment: So what? `+` casts its arguments to numbers anyway.